# Declaring class methods in class_methods or included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module M
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.b
      puts 'b'
    end
  end

  class_methods do
    def a
      puts 'a'
    end
  end
end

class H
  include M
end
```

Though `class_methods` is the standard way to define class methods in `ActiveSupport::Concern`, I do find a few examples where people declare class methods in `included` by using `self`.

Both works, so are there edgecases if class methods are defined inside `included`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if there is any difference. Perhaps `included` is there for Rails macros like `scope` and `has_many` while `class_methods` only lets you define pure Ruby?